# Обновление до php 5.6 на ubuntu 12

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Можно ли обновится до php 5.6 на Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (apache2), если можно, то как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На этом билде системы  это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно воспользоваться одним известным PPA в кругах PHP разработчиков [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) и установить просто PHP 5.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

В теории должно всё стать без проблем, версию потом проверьте командой:

```
php --version
```

Comment: В моём случае не работает.  Добавил скриншоты

Comment: @DraXXX только что проверил у себя, всё есть, sudo apt-get update делали?

Comment: Да, всё по инструкции.